# Extract binary attachment using httr

Tags: r, httr, rcurl

I have searched all over for an answer to this and I am coming up empty. I make a POST request to an API and it returns an object of `Content-Type: application/xop+xml`.

The response looks like this:

```
Response [https://...]
  Date: 2023-08-14 18:18
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:0ca94e9c-b817-4e87-9628-656cdd58be68"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
  Size: 18.3 MB
<BINARY BODY>
```

The attachment in this case should be a .zip file, but I have no idea how to extract it. I have tried using `writeBin` to save the content of the response to a file but resulting file is not able to be opened.

I was able to get a bit more information about the content here:

```
"Content-Type: application/octet-stream"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
"Content-ID: <565bcd99-ad2d-41c4-ac57-16f10557ae60-4229@api.xyz.com>"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
"Content-Disposition: attachment;name=\"tmp12345.zip\""
```

I am unable to provide a reproducible example since the API requires authentication, but I am hoping that someone can give me a hint on how I can successfully extract this zip file.

Comment: What exactly did your code look like? How did you call `writeBin`? Did you use `httr::content()` to get the content? Where did those additional headers come from? If you can't provide a reproducible example, is this API at least documented somewhere publicly available?

Comment: You can write response body to disk with `httr::write_disk()`, i.e. something like `POST("yoursecret.api", ..., write_disk("tmp.zip"))`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried to use `write_disk()` but it didn't work either. A file is created, but seems to be corrupted. @MrFlick - I used `writeBin(httr::content(r), "c:/temp/data.zip")`. I do not believe the API docs are publicly available. In my searching, it seems like the format of this content is special and not just a blob of binary data. It is somewhat explained here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.3?topic=data-mtomxop-soap

Comment: What is the output of `httr::content(..., as="text")`? Does it start with something readable? It doesn't seem httr expects multipart return values. You'll likely have to parse the content yourself especially if you only want to extract part of the response. According to that link the data should be base64 encoded in the response. You can use the boundary reported in the header to parse the different multipart sections.

Comment: The output you're asking about is actually where I got the additional header info from. So it is helpful, but I am still kind of stuck on how to proceed. I agree that I need to use the boundary to parse, but it isn't clear to me how to do that since it is binary or base64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution to this problem, although it is likely not the best. After comments from @MrFlick above, I started looking into searching/parsing vectors of raw data. I came across the function grepRaw which proved to be pretty useful. In my case, the "boundary" the API provided was not all that helpful since even once inside that boundary there were still headers that needed to be handled (perhaps there is a more elegant way). My solution was basically this:

```
v = content(response)
si = grepRaw(".zip", v) + 9
ei = grepRaw("--uuid", v, all = T)[3] - 1   #uuid appears three times
bytes = raw[si:ei]
writeBin(bytes, file_name)
```

For anyone else searching for an answer, I would suggest you do something similar and though trial and error (along with rawToChar) you can zero in on what parts of the response contain the binary data of interest. Not pretty, but it works.

If anyone comes up with a more elegant solution, feel free to share it here.